# There wasn't a single color I didn't see

Tags: grammar, phrases

I was talking about 'Gardens by the bay' which is in Singapore. I said:
"There were flowers from practically all over the world. It was so colorful *there wasn't a single color I didn't see."*

Is it correct to say things like:

1. *There wasn't a single color I didn't see.*
2. *There wasn't a single person I knew who could help me.*
3. *There wasn't a single house that wasn't haunted.*

If they are incorrect please let me know how to express this idea correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These look correct to me.  They use a double negative, but it is meaningful and correct.